# How to use Spark DataFrame with MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-spark

OK, I have known that I could use jdbc connector to create DataFrame with this command:

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", 
Map("url" -> "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/video_rcmd?user=root&password=123456",
"dbtable" -> "video"))
```

But I got this error: `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for ...`

And I have tried to add jdbc jar to spark_path with both commands but failed:

- `spark-shell --jars mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar`
- `SPARK_CLASSPATH=mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar spark-shell`

My Spark version is 1.3.0 while `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance` is worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar

Comment: Is there some specific reason you expect this to help? If so perhaps you could edit your post to include that.

Comment: I have updated to `mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar` and it worked.

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar works too, don't know what's wrong with 5.0.8.

Answer (score 1):

It is caused because the data frame does the find the the Mysql Connector Jar in the class path. This can be resolved by adding the jar to the spark class path as below:

Edit  /**spark/bin/compute-classpath.sh**  as

```
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$ASSEMBLY_JAR:yourPathToJar/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar"
```

Save the file and Restart the spark.